# **A curious number triangle.**

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request

Does the following number triangle occur in the literature?
Consider the sequences  $(1,{c_1},{c_2}, \cdots ) = (1,2,4,5,7,8, \cdots )$ of all integers not divisible by 3 and  $\left( {1,{d_1},{d_2}, \cdots } \right) = (1,1,2,2,3,3, \cdots )$ and form the table

$\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&1&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}\\
{}&{}&{}&{}&1&{{c_1}}&1&{}&{}&{}&{}\\
{}&{}&{}&1&{{c_1}}&{{c_2}}&{{d_1}}&1&{}&{}&{}\\
{}&{}&1&{{c_1}}&{{c_2}}&{{c_3}}&{{d_2}}&{{d_1}}&1&{}&{}\\
{}&1&{{c_1}}&{{c_2}}&{{c_3}}&{{c_4}}&{{d_3}}&{{d_2}}&{{d_1}}&1&{}\\
1&{{c_1}}&{{c_2}}&{{c_3}}&{{c_4}}&{{c_5}}&{{d_4}}&{{d_3}}&{{d_2}}&{{d_1}}&1
\end{array}$

It has the property that the sum of the $k$’th row is $(k+1)^2$ and the alternating sums of the rows are $1,0,3,0,5,0,7,....$

Comment: I haven't seen it before (although that is no guarantee that it isn't studied), but I think the numbers are to specific and in a non-trivial ordering for this to be some general triangle (like Pascals one)

Comment: A good reference for this kind of question is the famous Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences: https://oeis.org/